# A free Facebook sentiment analysis tool?

Tags: gratis, facebook, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Wondering if there's a lightweight sentiment analysis tool out there that's free and works with Facebook.

I know there are a few decent free tools that do this for Twitter ([Sentiment140](http://www.sentiment140.com/) comes to mind), but the only "free" options I can find that include Facebook are free trials for more robust services.

More specifically, I'm looking for an easy-to-use tool that allows quantification of Facebook-wide sentiment around specific keywords (ie. brands, events, etc.). I'd be satisfied with a tool that analyzes a smaller content scope, say, comments on a brand's Facebook page or comments within a specific post.

But I'd like to be able to analyze content from more pages than just those that I manage.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 but what content do you want to analyze? Your friends' text posts? Your own text posts? Images too? Liking behavior? Anything else? For what language? (Analyzing Korean is different from analyzing French). What kind of output do you want? Per-person histograms? All-time sentiment? Recent sentiment? With reliability indication?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. We really need some precise requirements here. Please read our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). What do you expect this tool to analyze (as Nicolas asks), how much training do you expect to provide, and what kind of output do you expect (level of detail, reliability, …)?

Comment: Natural language processing is extremely hard to get right, and even the best tools aren't very good yet. Sentiment analysis is one of those things where you get what you pay for; I'd strongly consider looking for a paid tool rather than a free one. (Paid tools will often give you demos, too, without you having to sign up.)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for the pointers. I edited the question for clarification. Hope it gets reopened!

Comment: Much better! But could you please also precise the language? No tool is able to analyze all languages, and some languages like Japanese are notably difficult to analyze.